# What is the computational complexity of calculating $\pi(x)$ exactly?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, computational-complexity

The prime counting function $\pi(x)$ has been determined for $x=10^{26}$.

The list of the $10^n$-th primes , however , ends at $n=18$. The $10^{18}$-th prime has $20$ digits.

Apparantly, the determination of $\pi(x)$ is easier than the determination of $p_n$ (the $n$-th prime).

> What is the computational complexity of determining $\pi(n)$ exactly ?
>
> What is the computational complexity of determining the $n$-th prime ?
>
> Is the second problem actually harder than the first ? (I think this is not the case because with binary search, it should be possible to determine $p_n$ nearly as efficiently as the determination of $\pi(n)$)

It is true that the problem is not of great practical interest because $li(x)$ is a very good approximation of $\pi(x)$. I am just curious how far the exact calculation could go on with the current computational power available.

Comment: see [Lagarias-Odlyzko's algorithm](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/53278/prime-counting-any-fast-alternatives-to-the-lagarias-miller-odlyzko-combinator) for computing $\pi(x)$. and  you are right, with binary search, computing the $n$th prime is $\Theta(\log_2(n) K(n \log n))$ where $K(x)$ is the complexity of computing $\pi(x)$

Comment: The nth prime computation is a relatively small amount more work, albeit the $n$ using corresponds to approx $n\log n$ for the count, which explains some of the discrepency.  Rather than a binary search, we typically use R(x) or some other good estimate, do a single prime count, then sieve the difference.  This works out best in practice.  For theory. my guess is that the complexity of sieving using the $O(x^{1/2}\log x)$ RH bound on li(x) will come out smaller than the cost of log(n) applications of $O(x^{2/3}/\log x)$ LMO or extended LMO.

Comment: I should also point out that your data is old.  $\pi(x)$ has been found for $x=10^{27}$, and $p_n$ for $n=10^{24}$.  One reason is that Kim Walisch has been working hard the last couple years on his primecount (and primesieve and primesum) program, including expanding to 128 bits and adding support for MPI.  In practice, a simple experiment on a 4770K: time for 10^17th prime, 1min57s.  Time for $\pi(p_{10^{17}})$:  1min56s.  The prime count time completely dominates, and we see that we wouldn't want to run it more than once.

Comment: @DanaJ Nice, always good to see new results.  Do you happen to know how the combinatorial method compares to the analytical method at these upper ranges?

Comment: @DanaJ Pretty cool! I did not find thes values anywhere. Could you show us the values and perhaps a reference ?

Comment: @Peter, nth prime at https://oeis.org/A006988 .  Prime count at https://oeis.org/A006880.  Announcement of result and later verification for 10^27 at http://www.mersenneforum.org/showthread.php?t=20473.

Comment: @Deedlit, I cannot give a definitive comparison.  Deleglise and Rivat's 1996 paper notes that the analytical methods have better asymptotic efficiency, but large constants.  I suspect a big issue that the combinatorial methods are able to be implemented well by people with reasonable programming skill and the tenacity to go through Riesel's book and the various papers.  There are at least 3 open source implementations, plus the private research ones.  Contrast with the analytical methods, which seem to be far more inscrutable.  Currently the comb methods seem to be faster in practice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Right now there are two competing methods for determining $\pi(x)$ when $x$ is large: the combinatorial method of Meissel-Lehmer-Lagarias-Miller-Odlyzko-Deleglise-Rivat (see [here](http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1985-44-170/S0025-5718-1985-0777285-5/)), which requires $O(\frac{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(\log x)^2})$ time and $O(x^{\frac{1}{3}}(\log x)^2)$ space, and the analytical method of Lagarias-Odlyzko (see [here](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/~odlyzko/doc/arch/analytic.pi.of.x.pdf)), which requires $O(x^{\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon})$ time and $O(x^{\frac{1}{4}+\epsilon})$ space. (Although actually, the latter method can be modified to require $O(x^{\frac{3-2\delta}{5}+\epsilon})$ time and $O(x^{\delta+\epsilon})$ space for $0 \le \delta \le \frac{1}{4}$.)

Interestingly, the record of $\pi(10^{26})$ was obtained using the combinatorial method, which is slower asymptotically; perhaps the crossover point has not yet been reached.  Another factor is likely the difficulty of implementing the analytical method.

As you say, we can use $\pi(n)$ to determine $p_n$, and the computational complexities will not be much different asymptotically; however, the difference is likely enough to cause $p_n$ to lag behind, since we would need to evaluate $\pi(n)$ many times just to determine one value of $p_n$.  But, I would say that the difference of a factor of $10^6$ between the two records is probably due to less attention paid to $p_n$.

Answer (score 1):

According to Kim Walisch's [benchmark](https://github.com/kimwalisch/primecount#benchmarks) Xavier Gourdon's method is the faster.

Its time complexity is  $O(\frac{x^{\frac{2}{3}}}{(\log x)^2})$ which seems to be same as Deleglise-Rivat's, but performs better due to constant optimizations.

**Time Complexity over time:**

1798 : Legendre => $O(n^{3/4})$

1870 : Meissel => $O(n^{2/3}.log^{1/3}n)$

1959 : [Lehmer](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-3/issue-3/On-the-exact-number-of-primes-less-than-a-given/10.1215/ijm/1255455259.full) => $O(n^{2/3})$ — popularly known as Missel-Lehmer

1985 : [Lagarias, Miller and Odlyzko](http://www.dtc.umn.edu/%7Eodlyzko/doc/arch/meissel.lehmer.pdf) => $O(n^{2/3}/log\ n)$ — popularly known as LMO

1996 : [M. Deleglise, J. Rivat](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1996-65-213/S0025-5718-96-00674-6/S0025-5718-96-00674-6.pdf)    => $O(n^{2/3}/log^2n)$

2001 : Xavier Gourdon => $O(n^{2/3} / log^2n)$ (constant factor for both time and memory improved) — default algo for [Kimwalisch's](https://www.mankier.com/1/primecount) package

2015 : [Douglas Staple](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1503.01839.pdf) => $O(n^{2/3} / log^2n)$ (constant factor for memory improved)

Comment: Where did you get the complexities for Legendre, Meissel and Lehmer.  Legendre's method is Omega(x) (his sum has that many terms).  Meissel's is not clear, but Pomerance and Crandall state that his and Lehmer's are Omega(x).